# Validate mysql query if NULL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is this query possible in mysql?

If query returns null, then `set x = false` else `set x = true`

**Query**

```
SET @s1 = (SELECT * FROM `wo_ticket_details_replay` 
WHERE message NOT LIKE "[ SYSTEM%" AND `sv_number`='0715201569998')
CASE WHEN @s1 = NULL THEN
  x = 'false'
ELSE
  x = 'true'
END CASE;
```

Comment: double quotes, `is null`

Comment: LIKE with double quotes is useless

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery with [EXISTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html).